# Extjs 4 checkcolumn not visible

Tags: grid, extjs4

I have a an Grid with a column that must be a checkcolumn, i use this code 
there are two rows in the grid but the checkcolumn looks empty. When i click on the checkcolumn the console.log returns correctly the changed boolean. But i see nothing in that column.

```
xtype: 'checkcolumn',
header: 'REDACTEUR',
dataIndex: 'REDACTEUR',
width: 75,
editor: {
xtype: 'checkbox'                            
},
renderer : function(value) {
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 8):

you have to manually include the css for the checkcolumn xtype like this:`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/extjs4/examples/ux/css/CheckHeader.css">`

Answer (score 2):

if your app is generated by `Sencha CMD`, you need to execute the following command on your project directory

```
sencha app build
```

after this command has finished, reload your app on your browser and you can now see your `checkcolumn`.

Answer (score 1):

extra js file is needed, try to seek Ext file named '`CheckColumn.js`' and included it in your script. Or set the Ext's ux path at the beginning of the script also works.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my disappearing checkbox/radio CSS problem in ExtJs 6.01 by running 2 commands:

1) sencha app build development
2) sencha app refresh

Refresh was important