# SDK2: checkboxes in a RallyGrid column?

Tags: javascript, sdk, grid, rally

I'd like to add a column with checkboxes in a rally grid (something like "Select Default").  It looks like that should be pretty simple using the 'checkcolumn' xtype.  But that requires you to link in some additional extjs styles, and I'm not sure how to do that within the Rally extjs framework:

[Extjs 4 checkcolumn not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469482/extjs-4-checkcolumn-not-visible)

Here's an example of such a column in ext-js: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/edit-grid.html

Is there a way do this with a Rally grid?

I ended up using a quick and dirty solution based on the anwser below:

```
{text: 'Default', dataIndex:'selected', align: 'center', width: 50, renderer: function(value, style, item, rowIndex) {
    return "<input type='radio' name='primaryIndex' alt='"+ rowIndex + "' " + (value ? "checked='checked'" : "") + ">";
}},
```

AND:

```
        checkRadioClick: function(event) {
            var button = event.getTarget('input[type="radio"]');

            if (button) {
                       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Ext's grid (which the Rally grid extends) doesn't support a checkbox column.  The closest thing that comes out of the box is the Boolean column:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Boolean

This is because the grid expects you to have to click a cell to initiate an edit and a checkbox column is immediately editable without that action.

That given, I think you should be able to render a checkbox column by simply specifying a renderer for that column in your column config.  It may be a little challenging to get the values back out of the grid when they change though since the values will not have been committed to the underlying records in the store (because no actual edit was triggered).

There is also a user submitted CheckColumn here that you may be able to use or at least as an example to get started:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/CheckColumn.html#Ext-ux-CheckColumn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is new with one of the newer preview versions?  I did this:

```
Ext.create( 'Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            selType: 'checkboxmodel',
            selModel: {
                injectCheckbox: 1,
                mode: 'SIMPLE',
                listeners: {
                    selectionchange: function( model, selected ) {
                        // do stuff
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            }
```